# JQuery download progress in Opera 12

Tags: jquery, download, opera, progress

First of all see a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/xYC9n/2/) on jsfiddle.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/22.0/win32/rm/Firefox%20Setup%2022.0.exe',
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    progress: function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = 100 * evt.loaded / evt.total;
            $("#percentDownload").html(percentComplete);
            $("#downloadSize").html(evt.loaded);
            $("#allSize").html(evt.total);
        };
    },
    complete: function(jqXhr, textStatus) {
        //
    }
});
```

I'm using a [jquery-ajax-progress](https://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress) patch by *englercj*

And here is a **Opera 12.16 build 1860** browser statistics (on *Windows 8.1 Professional preview with Media Center Build 9431* with all updates on 19.07.2013):
*Downloaded percent: 189.01157552527454 Downloaded bytes: 41051288 Size bytes: 21718928*

**Google Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m**, **IE 11.0.9431.0**, **Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)** and **Firefox 22.0** works perfect and shows 100 percents and correct downloaded size.

What the matter with Opera? And how I can fix this?

**Don't tell me about Opera 15, please.**

Comment: seems like a bug in opera... check comments in [this article about xhr from opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/xhr2/) - some users had similar problems..

Comment: @betatester07, I see the [demo](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/9482/xhr-progressevents.html) for uploading file progress, presented in [this](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/xhr2/#xhrprogressevents) article, but he works fine. Yeah, for download progress it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

For Opera 12 to behave you gotta (re)set the content type header of the response like so:

```
$.ajax({
  //…
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
  }
  //…
});
```